# Can't Find Element XPath, Skip & Write Placeholder Text

Tags: python, selenium

This is a loop for scraping several elements. Sometimes *price* isn't always found. Instead of passing through except - I need to print/write a value for those times when no price is found. The reason being is when it just passes through, it mismatches the variable values when printing (title, link, image, price). Hopefully, you can see my logic below in what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm also attaching a screenshot so you can see what I mean.

[image]

```
#finds titles
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealTitle']/span")
titles = []
for title in deal_title:
    titles.append(title.text)

#finds links
deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row dealDetailContainer']/div/a[@id='dealTitle']")
links = []
for link in deal_link:
    links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

#finds images
deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealImage']/div/div/div/img")
images = []
for image in deal_image:
    images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))

try:

    deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
    prices = []
    for price in deal_price:
        prices.append(price.text)

except NoSuchElementException:
    price = ("PRINT/WRITE THIS TEXT INSTEAD OF PASSING")

#writes to html
for title, link, image, price in zip(titles, links, images, prices):
    f.write("<tr class='border'><td class='image'>" + "<img src=" + image + "></td>" + "<td class='title'><a href=" + link + '>'">" + title + "</a></td><td class='price'>" + price + "</td></tr>")
```

Comment: Anyone else have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you show the HTML code of above screenshot? And I recommend you to find all cards of each sale good, then find title, link, price inside card.

Comment: Hi there, the price xpath, div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight'] does not exist in the places where there is no price indicated on the screenshot.

Comment: Here's the link so you can see the source: https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10?gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8

Comment: @Bronson77 `I need to print/write a value for those times when no price is found` will be a tough ask as _Selenium_ interacts with the _HTML DOM_ and will be too broad as a question. At most you can skip printing the items which don't have a price.

Comment: @DebanjanB You can see in this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/hSbUH24 - with my code "as is" the price will shift to the first one that is skipped and so on. It pairs the wrong price with the wrong product. Can I skip the price without it shifting?

Comment: @Bronson77 , you can try to append empty string or `None` for those items without price: `except NoSuchElementException: prices.append('')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

capabilities = {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions':  {
    'useAutomationExtension': False,
    'forceDevToolsScreenshot': True,
    'args': ['--start-maximized', '--disable-infobars']
  }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver_2.38.exe', desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get("""https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10? 
    gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,
    dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,
    includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,
    dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&
    pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&
    pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8""")

time.sleep(15)

golds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".widgetContainer #widgetContent > div.singleCell")
print("found %d golds" % len(golds))  

template = """\
    <tr class="border">
        <td class="image"><img src="{0}"></td>\
        <td class="title"><a href="{1}">{2}</a></td>\
        <td class="price">{3}</td>
    </tr>"""

lines = []

for gold in golds:
    goldInfo = {}

    goldInfo['title'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealTitle > span').text
    goldInfo['link'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealTitle').get_attribute('href')
    goldInfo['image'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('#dealImage img').get_attribute('src')

    try:
        goldInfo['price'] = gold.find_element_by_css_selector('.priceBlock > span').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        goldInfo['price'] = 'No price display'

    print goldInfo['title']

    line = template.format(goldInfo['image'], goldInfo['link'], goldInfo['title'], goldInfo['price'])
    lines.append(line)

html = """\
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                {0}
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>\
"""

f = open('./result.html', 'w')
f.write(html.format('\n'.join(lines)))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried running that code and I'm not getting any html output, however not getting any errors either. On line two, I would assume it should be "browser.find" since that's how I defined it in my example? I changed that out, but still no output.

Comment: you can use `driver.find_element_by_xxx()` and `webelement.find_element_by_xxx()`, more detail at here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement,   Can you add debug code like print in my code to see the value of `goodInfo` in for loop

Comment: Hi there, I tried running your updated code but it doesn't output. I've tried adding in debugging code and can't get anything to print at any point. Have you tried running this on your side?

Comment: I move the `driver.get` into function and add `time.sleep` before find elements.  I got expected output on local.

Comment: I get print str(goldInfo) as invalid syntax

Comment: Also if this were working locally, webdriver would throw an error for "find_element_by_css" that's not valid, it's "find_element_by_css_selector"?

Comment: @Bronson, I write a protractor(Another web automation tool) script use the same logic and css selector as in my answer, it work fine on my local.  You are right it should be `find_element_by_css_selector`, and change `print str(goldInfo)` to `print goldInfo.title`.  You not init the variable `f` in your code showed in the screenshot.  Please do necessary change, because I don't have the context of your script,  so my answer only focus the key part. Also for debug code, you need to add accordingly. And the last 3 code lines has wrong indention

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to run by copying your code. I am opening "f" at the top, so that's not the issue. Why all the printing inside the code? I want to write to file, not print. There still seems to be syntax errors. Also the "def readGoldsinfo()" when removed the browser will load the page. If that code is present, it will not load. See the screenshot for my current code: https://imgur.com/a/dxvRiAo

Comment: I'm new python, but there are tons of syntax errors in the code. So I'm not sure what's supposed to be there and what's not. What's the purpose of def readGoldsinfo()?

Comment: @Bronson, I updated python code which run pass on my local, please change `executable_path='./chromedriver_2.38.exe'` to your value, after run `result.html` will be generated in current directory

Comment: Thanks for all your help. That finally worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you have got problem with loading some page elements "on time".

The elements you want to scrap may not load yet when you are reading them.

To prevent this, you can use **[explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)**(the script will wait specified time until specified element loads).

When using this, there will be a smaller chance you miss some values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not the issue. The script will scrape all of the needed values, but sometimes a price is not listed on the item for sale.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can skip the price as well. I am providing you an alternative approach where you can create a *List* of the available *prices* and the respective *images* as follows :

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10?gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8")
  #finds images
  deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span//preceding::img[1]")
  images = []
  for image in deal_image:
      images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))

  #finds prices
  deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
  prices = []
  for price in deal_price:
      prices.append(price.text)

  #print the information
  for image, price in zip(images, prices):
      print(image, price)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31zt-ovKJqL._AA210_.jpg $9.25
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/610%2BKAfr72L._AA210_.jpg $15.89
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41whkQ1m0uL._AA210_.jpg $31.49
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41cAbUWEdoL._AA210_.jpg $259.58 - $782.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51raHLFC8wL._AA210_.jpg $139.56
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41fuZZwdruL._AA210_.jpg $41.24
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51N2rdMSh0L._AA210_.jpg $19.50 - $20.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/515DbJhCtOL._AA210_.jpg $22.97
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51OzOZrj1rL._AA210_.jpg $109.95
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31-QDRkNbhL._AA210_.jpg $15.80
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41vXJ9fvcIL._AA210_.jpg $88.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51fKqo2YfcL._AA210_.jpg $21.85
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31GcGUXz9TL._AA210_.jpg $220.99 - $241.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41sROkWjnpL._AA210_.jpg $40.48
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51vXMFtZajL._AA210_.jpg $22.72
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/512s5ZrjoFL._AA210_.jpg $51.99
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51A8Nfvf8eL._AA210_.jpg $8.30
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51aDac6YN5L._AA210_.jpg $18.53
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31SQON%2BiOBL._AA210_.jpg $10.07
  ```
- Link:

  ```
  https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_page_10?gb_f_deals1=enforcedCategories:2972638011,dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,includedAccessTypes:,page:10,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:32&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=ZDV4YBQJFDVR3PAY4ZBS&ie=UTF8
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: price_picture]